# How to reverse a section of bit digits in C?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

In short, if I'm dealing with a number in binary, like `0000 0110`, and suppose I want only the last 3 bits to be reversed, are there any methods that translate this into `0000 0011`?

I have seen other questions and resources where the `reverse bits method` is implemented but returns the whole number reversed (i.e. `0110 0000`, not `0000 0011`).

Would it be enough to just reverse it, as done in the standard methods, and then shift it as much as is necessary? Or is there a more direct way to achieve this?

Format: `unsigned int reverse_select_bits(int number, int num_bits) { ... }`

Comment: Are you only interested in reversing the last N bits, or are you interested in reversing N bits from bit position A to B?  Is there an upper bound on how many bits you'd need to reverse (like 8, perhaps), or is it limited to the size of `int`?

Comment: For my purposes, I would only need the last `n` bits. A reversal of an arbitrary section in the middle of the bit sequence is (I think) overkill.

Answer (score 1):

## Simple reference

See http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#BitReverseObvious is a good start for you to see how is really should be done.  There are some rather fun techniques described there.  Especially have a look at

http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ReverseByteWith64Bits

to understand how to think about these problems.

### HINT A

For arbitrary word size use the obvious method after using a mask to mask out the bits you wish to save:

```
typeof(word) preserve_mask = \
     ((1 <<  8*sizeof(word)) - 1) & ~(typeof(word))((1 << K) - 1);
```

Where K is the number of bits you wish to 'reverse'.  preserve_mask will give you a mask to save the part of the word that you do not wish to flip.  Note that above is not really C code but concept that you'd have to implement.  I suggest first doing it within the limits of your CPU; and then deal with arbitrary precision later (and only if it's needed).

### Hint B

Can you see how this can be done for arbitrary length using a generalization of ReverseByteWith64Bits?

Can it be done piece-meal over N bits where N ≢ 0 (mod 8) ? can you use the result from Hint A?

Let me know if you need further help

Comment: cool. I'll take a read through that material and try to implement the method by your hints ;)

Comment: If you do it correctly :) you can essentially unroll all loops ^^

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have to reverse three bits, prepare a table of eight entries is the easiest way to do it.

```
int rev_table[8] = {0, 4, 2, 6, 1, 5, 3, 7};
int rev_last_three_bits(int v) {
    return (v & (~7)) | rev_table[v&7];
}
```

Comment: Sorry about me being not clear... I gave 3 as an example, in which case I want this number to be arbitrary. I'll edit the post.

Comment: Oh, in that case...we need a more sophisticated solution.

Answer (score -1):

Implemented a function that can swap two certain bit in a char.

You can reverse any section of bit with the help of this funciton.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void swap_bits(char *a,unsigned char p1,unsigned char p2)
{
    if (p1==p2) return;//don't need swap
    unsigned char bit1=(1<<p1)&(*a);//access the bit in position 1(0-indexed);
    unsigned char bit2=(1<<p2)&(*a);//access the bit in position 2(0-indexed);
    (*a)^=bit1;//set the bit in position 1 to 0.
    if (bit2) (*a)^=1<<p1;// if bit2 is 1 then set the bit in position to 1 
    (*a)^=bit2;
    if (bit1) (*a)^=1<<p2;
}
int main()
{
    char a=0x06;
    swap_bits(&a,0,2);
    printf("%x\n",a);
}
```

Comment: I like this idea, but it seems too costly... I'm dealing with time-crunching calculations, and this methods seems to overlap too many repeated calls. I think this could be optimized though to prevent that; I just can't think of a way right now.

Comment: swapping bits can be done a lot faster by using masks and xor